# InfluxDB aggregate on TOP function and display in Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm new to InfluxDB and Grafana. I'm using version 1.7.4 and playing through the Grafana Twitter example in the Spring Cloud Data Flow workshop. There is basically a `hashtags` measurement like this:

```
select * from hashtags limit 10
name: hashtags
time                       htag             value
----                       ----             -----
2019-03-07T07:46:59.096Z   現実見ろ           0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.097Z   キズのしょち松さん   0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.097Z   競馬              0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.098Z   PerthTanapon     0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.098Z   終活              0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.106Z   capolavoro       0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.108Z   Cenizas          0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.108Z   design           0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.108Z   hyungwon         0    
2019-03-07T07:46:59.108Z   ざわちん           0
```

In the [example screencast](https://youtu.be/hWLhrXIepLs?t=354) the author creates a pie chart that is supposed to display the top 10 hashtags on Twitter. The video shows that he creates a query like this:

`SELECT sum("value") FROM "hashtags" GROUP BY "htag" SLIMIT 10`

The problem here is that the chart only represents 10 hashtags in alphabetical order. What I want is the Top 10 hashtags. Now InfluxDB doesn't have a order by clause on tags or fields so I tried to come up with my own query that tries to solve my problem using `TOP()` and a subquery:

`select top("sum", "htag",10) from (SELECT sum("value") FROM "hashtags" GROUP BY "htag")` which yields the correct result:

```
name: hashtags
time                 top  htag
----                 ---  ----
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 3172 TwoOfUs
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 2301 BestCoverSong
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 1480 เชงเม้ง
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 1337 투모로우바이투게더
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 1117 GOT7
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 1106 MeMyselfAndI
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 848  백현
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 848  ยุบพรรค
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 842  Jus2
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 781  TOMORROW_X_TOGETHER
```

The problem with grafana is that it doesn't properly display my results in the pie chart

[image]

What am I missing? I saw that the first query has a grouping so the query result looks like this:

```
name: hashtags
tags: htag=01JokowiAs1k
time                 sum
----                 ---
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 0

name: hashtags
tags: htag=01JokowiLagi
time                 sum
----                 ---
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 9

name: hashtags
tags: htag=01OptimisIndonesiaMaju
time                 sum
----                 ---
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 7
```

How can I achieve that grouping on my query?

Answer (score -1):

Try additional `GROUP BY "htag"`:

```
SELECT TOP("sum", "htag",10) FROM 
  (SELECT SUM("value") FROM "hashtags" GROUP BY "htag")
GROUP BY "htag"
```

Comment: Thought about this as well. But this gives me just the groups of the sum of the first 10 alphabetical hashtags (equal to the result of the first query)